# How to order by for customer week number which contains year number too

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

I have a table with one row

employee(date)

```
date
52 week in 2021
23 week in 2022
34 week in 2021
1 week in 2022
52 week in 2022
```

I tried the below query but it's not working

```
select date from employee order by date desc
```

I want to order by in desc for above column. I'm expecting output like below

```
date
52 week in 2022
23 week in 2022
1 week in 2022
52 week in 2021
34 week in 2021
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting year and week part and then performing sort:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY RIGHT(date,4) DESC, CAST(LEFT(date,2) AS INT) DESC
```